# Subset by row number within magrittr chain

Tags: r, magrittr

I'm experimenting with magrittr chains using grep/gsub etc

This works well

```
top_url <- "http://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/ae-waiting-times-and-activity/"

readLines(top_url) %>% grep("SitReps", .)
```

The next step is to return a subset using the row numbers.  I've tried this, but it does not work.

```
readLines(top_url) %>% .[grep("SitReps", .)]
```

Can this be done?

Comment: You could just use `value = TRUE` within `grep`, something like `readLines(top_url) %>% grep("SitReps", ., value = TRUE)`. Other than that, the `magrittr` way would be using `extract`, though I can't figure out how

Comment: If this is just an exercise then exercise away, but if you really want to extract info from HTML look at the `rvest` package or any of the other packages for scraping - see the R Web Tech Task View for more.

Comment: @Spacedman - I had not seen rvest before, installing now

Comment: Adding a small comment for users who come across this: if you are subsetting by e.g. which.max() for a column, `.[which.max(.$COLNAME),]` actually does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option would be just using `value = TRUE` within `grep` (which will save you one extra operator)

```
readLines(top_url) %>% grep("SitReps", ., value = TRUE)
```

Or just modify your own code and use `[` in the follwoing manner

```
readLines(top_url) %>% `[`(grep("SitReps", .))
```

Comment: I didn't know grep had that options - very useful.  The second suggestion using '[' doesn't work for me - have I missed something?

Comment: What error are you getting? Maybe try to update `magrittr` the latest version using `install.packages("magrittr")`. It works just fine for me.

Comment: That was it - 1.5 did the job.  Is the application of the single bracket as a function specific to magrittr or does it apply anywhere?

Comment: No, `[` is a function in R. E.g., when you do `df[df$A == 1, ]`, R actually does `"["(df$A == 1, )`. Take a look in `?"["`. Actually `[` is a generic S3 method and it triggers `"[.data.frame"` when called for a `data.frame` object

Answer (score 3):

Beside the option in David's comment, you could also do:

```
readLines(top_url) %>% extract(grep("SitReps", .))
```

But I would prefer David's approach.

Note that you only subset a character vector here, which doesn't have row numbers.

Comment: That was actually my first try, but that gives me errors. I wonder if it's because my `magrittr` is not up to date or something

Comment: Yeah, I've updated to the latest version and it works now... Too bad I didn't do that at the start lol

Comment: is `extract` coming from `tidyr`?

Comment: Then you need `magrittr::extract` if user has loaded `tidyr` in search path before `magrittr`  (and ignores the masking warning)

Comment: @Spacedman Actually, it was not the case.  I didn't load `tidyr` and did tried `magrittr::extract` .  It worked on a fresh R console.

Comment: It broke me :( Odd for two things in the Hadleyverse to clash like this though...